# Can not boot my ubuntu partition

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

being honest, I'm completely lost on this.

This is what happened.

I issued 'tasksel remove kubuntu-desktop' because I wanted to get back to the good-old gnome desktop ( I have installed Ubuntu 18.04).

after that I was left with no desktop (no GUI) at all.

So, I ran a live version of Ubuntu on that computer in order to try to get back the desktop.

I managed to install it, before that though, I ran boot-repair tool (for not quite-well remember what reason).

Now, I have several options in grub, none of those work for booting my Ubuntu system though. The options are:
EFI/ubuntu/fbx64.efi
EFI/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi
EFI/ubuntu/mmx64.efi

among others related to windows boot.

This is the status generated by boot-repair:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KMsGfYmf52/

Regarding to my bios, I have secure boot disabled.

Can anyone tell me how to get my ubuntu system back?

Regards.

Comment: Did you try logging into a virtual terminal (At the X screen with no desktop, type ctrl + alt +F3) give your username and password, and from there, install a desktop.

Comment: Report did not show the grub.cfg in your install? But it shows that files in list of files in partition. I might try the advanced mode and full reinstall of grub and latest kernel. The rerun report and post that if it does not work. Also try booting recovery mode if you get grub menu and cannot otherwise boot.

Comment: Hi @ubfan1,at first I was shown only with a tty terminal, nothing else, and at the time I could not manage to make my wireless network to connect from there (I really really think it was because of when I remove the kubuntu-desktop it remove everything, even wireless card drivers) in order to install the desktop.
Then it was when I decided to use a live ubuntu disc. From there, well, I ran the boot-repair tool which I think made matters worse.

Comment: @oldfred Ima try that. Ley you know once it done.

Comment: Hi. I've run the utility (boot repair) with no success. I still can not get into my ubuntu operating system.
Within windows I deleted folder boot repair, ubuntu an debian from the EFI partition, the I ran again the boot repair with no success. Now, regarding ubuntu, I have  only the option

Comment: EFI/ubuntu/mmx64 which the Shim UEFI Key management.

Other options are:
Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi
Windows Boot UEFI loaer
Windows Boot UEFI fbx64.efi

This options:
Windows Boot UEFI loaer
shows me these messages:
Failed to open \EFI\Boot\grubx64.efi - Not found
Failed to load image \EFI\Boot\grubx64.efi: Not found
start_image() returned Not Found

Comment: Do I need to re-install the whole operating system?

Comment: By the way, this is the last report I have from boot repair:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/yqBnPY7QXQ

Comment: Furthermore, at the end of the report it mentions this:
Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sda1/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi file!

How can I actually do that?

And looking at EFI\ubuntu (from my windows partition, which is sda1) I see the following files:
grubx64.efi
shimx64.efi
mmx64.efi
BOOTX64.CSV
grub.cfg